# Difference between fixed effects, main effects and simple effects

Tags: regression, experiment-design, random-effects-model

I read through [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode) on the difference between **fixed**, **random** and **mixed-effects**.

However, I have also heard about **main** and **simple** effects. What are they and how do they relate to the ones above?